# Read input directly if input from pipe is invalid

Tags: c, pipe, stdin

If I receive invalid input from pipe i.e.

```
echo -1 | my_command
```

`my_command` is my C program and I can modify it. Is there any way to prompt the user to enter valid input, i.e. changing the input stream from pipe to stdin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. The pipe *is* your stdin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stdin` *is* the pipe, what you mean is probably open the console instead. That's certainly possible:

```
freopen("/dev/tty", "r", stdin);
```

(This should work on any Unix-style platform. Be sure to check for errors, as always.)

Comment: Yeah, I mean opening console only. My bad!! stdin is pipe only. That solves the problem. Thanks.